# React Native TouchableOpacity onPress not working with FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity, flatlist

I created a FlatList of selectable countries like this

```
export default function Body() {
 const data = useData();
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
 const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
 return item.empty ? (
  <View style={styles.blank} />
  ) : (
  <Country
    text={item.name}
    onPress={() => setSelected(item.id)}
    selected={item.id === selected}
  >
    <item.Flag />
  </Country>
 );
};
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    extraData={selected}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.flatlist}
    numColumns={3}
  />
</View>
);
}
```

And I defined a Country component like this

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "./Style";

export default function Country({ children, text, onPress, selected }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={[styles.view, selected && styles.selected]}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>{children}</TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Everything was working perfectly fine and I was able to select a country but somehow now the touchableOpacity onPress event seems broken and the elements are no longer pressable. for things to work I need to edit and undo edit on the data array or the Country component. Is this a RN bug causing things to fail?

Answer (score 0):

I found the root problem. Turns out that the problem lays on the stylesheet of the Country component wrapper. I gave it an `alignSelf: "baseline"` don't know why but removing it solved the hassle